# If $S$ is a subset of a vector space $V$, then $span(S)$ equals the intersection of all subspaces of $V$ that contain $S$.

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

**Attempt**

$S$ is a subset of subspace $W_i\subseteq V$ for all $i$, then any element $\sum^n_{i=1}c_iv_i$ in $Span(S)$ is an element of subspace $W_i$ for all $i$, so $Span(S)\subseteq \bigcap W_i$ for all $i$.

Consider $y\in\bigcap W_i$, and every $W_i$ contains $S$, hence each $W_i$ contains $Span(S)$ as each $W_i$ is a subspace, being closed under addition and multiplication.

I was about to argue every $y$ is obtainable by some linear combination of elements in $\bigcap W_i$ (intersection of the subspace is subspace),

then every element in $\bigcap W_i$ is also an element of $Span(S)$ as every $W_i$ contains $S$, thereby $\bigcap W_i\subseteq Span(S)$.

However, the last argument still cannot convince me that what if there exists some subspace $Y$ such that $Span(S)\subsetneq Y\subseteq \bigcap W_i$.

Please help me with explicitly arguing that every element in $\bigcap W_i$ is also an element of $Span(S)$.

Comment: Notice that $span(S)$ is itself a subspace that contains $S$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y\in\bigcap W_i$ be arbitrary. This means that $y$ belongs to each subspace of $V$ containing $S$. But $\text{Span}(S)$ is one of these subspaces. Therefore, $y\in\text{Span}(S)$. Therefore, $\bigcap W_i\subseteq\text{Span}(S)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\operatorname{span} S$ is a subspace containing all elements of $S$, so the intersection of all subspaces containing $S$ is a subset of $\operatorname{span} S$.